# Convert xml attribute and elements to elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need a  help in XML transformations.  My Input xml is

```
<Book BookType="PAPER" BookID="23456" AuthorCD="578"> my Book Name </Book>
```

I need the output in below format

```
<Book> 
 <BookType>PAPER</BookType>
 <BookID>23456</BookID>
 <AuthorCD>578</AuthorCD>
 <Book>my Book Name </Book>
</Book>
```

I am trying below transformation

```
<xsl:template match=Book">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:if test="@*">
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:element>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:if>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But its out put is coming like below. How to get the "my book name" is not appearing in expected format.

```
<Book xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <BookType>PAPER</BookType>
    <BookID>23456</BookID>
    <AuthorCD>578</AuthorCD>
     my Book Name
</<Book>
```

Answer (score 4):

Write a template for the `Book` element and another one for its attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="Book">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <Book>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Book>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Book/@*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Like it! It is more in XSLT functional style, without if and for-each

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "my book name" output because default template for text nodes kicks in. 
Default template rules work as given below:

- get text value for attributes and text nodes
- apply defined templates (or defaults if nothing is defined).
- ignore comments and processing instructions

According to above rules, atrribute names and element names are not to be found in output.

[Learn more about default templates](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xmlnut/ch08_07.htm)

For your solution to work as expected, you need to add rule for text nodes inside Book element:

```
<xsl:template match="Book/text()">
 <Book>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </Book>
</xsl:template>
```